# Why can we change the order of "exists" and "for all"?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

[image]

This is lemma 5 in section 12.2 from Ireland and Rosen's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory". $D$ is the ring of algebraic integers of an algebraic number field $F$, and $N(x)$ denotes the norm of $x$ with respect to $F/\mathbb Q$.

Why do we allow $M$ to be dependent on $\gamma$, if $M$ isn't dependent on $\alpha, \beta$?

Comment: It’s difficult to be sure given that I don’t have the rest of the proof, but I’m guessing the $M$ ultimately does not depend on $\gamma$ (or perhaps that there are finitely many possible $\gamma$). Without any further argument, it seems incorrect to change these two quantifiers indeed.

Comment: I noticed now that the $M$ chosen afterwards is actually independent of $\gamma$. Thank you